# how to identify an html div id which starts with some pattern using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

normally we use something like this to identify Id using jquery

```
 $("#PhotoId").html('some html');
```

here we get the html  (say div) having id 'PhotoId'
what if the id is partially dynamic i.e.
lets say there are multiple photoes

each id would start with 'PhotoId'
EX.

```
 $("#PhotoId" + result.Id).html(some html');
```

NOW,
i want to identify html(div) which starts with 'PhotoId' 
how can it be done

Comment: you should accept an answer or enhance your question (why none of the answers fits, ...)

Answer (score 5):

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
var elements = $('div[id^=PhotoId]');
```

another approach would be:
give the elements a class, eg. `photoId`, then you can do something like that

```
var elements = $('div.photoId');
```

this would not cause jQuery to parse the `id`-attributes of the `div`, instead jQuery would do a simple match on the class

Comment: each time the result.Id would change how to bind it with...
$('div[id^=PhotoId]')
ie div id that would start with 'PhotoId' and has dynamic 'result.Id' how to identify this

$("#PhotoId" + result.Id)

Comment: do you need the `id` to work with, or just the containers? if you do not need the `id` my solution finishes it. otherwise you'll need some parsing - therefore let me know, and i will expand my answer!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Id you could give each div that you wish to identify a specific class which you could then target using jQuery:

```
$(".photo").html('some html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$("div[id^=PhotoId]").html(); //take all div with id starting with the word 'PhotoId'
```